# Question on the concept of symmetry of cubic polynomial's graph

Tags: graphing-functions, cubics

Give the cubic polynomial $ y = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$ which is symmetric about the line $x=k$ then derive a relation between $a,b, c, d$ $and$ $k$.

I have attempted this question and used the fact that at the point of symmetry either the first derivative must be zero or not defined. However I am not convinced by my method and feel I have left something out and not considered it. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If the polynomial is $p(x)$, symmetry about the line $x=k$ implies $p(k+t)=p(k-t)$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

EDIT: I got $6\,a{k}^{2}t+2\,a{t}^{3}+4\,bkt+2\,ct=t\cdot(6\,a{k}^{2}+2\,a{t}^{2}+4\,bk+2\,c)=0$.
Since this must hold for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$, it follows that $6\,a{k}^{2}+2\,a{t}^{2}+4\,bk+2\,c=0$.
Once again, that this holds for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$ implies $a=0$. Hence, the relations we derive are

$$a=2bk+c=0.$$

---

Notice that we could have derived $a=0$ *a priori* from the fact that $p$ has odd degree.
Indeed, if that were not the case, then $\lim_{x\to\infty}p(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to-\infty}p(x)$ would have opposite signs, so the graph of $p$ couldn't be symmetric about a vertical line.

Then, the quesiton would reduce to finding a relation on a quadratic polynomial. It is well known that these polynomials have parabolas for graphs, and that their only vertical line of symmetry is the one that crosses the point of minimum/maximum, at $x=\frac{-c}{2b}$. If it sounds unfamiliar, notice that these polynomials are usually described as $q(x)=ax^2+bx+c$, and this point is then usually written as $x=\frac{-b}{2a}$.

Comment: Can you please tell me how you achieved this result?

Comment: Also, won't we be introducing another variable t and hence make the question more complex??

Comment: This simply follows from symmetry. If $\big(k+t,p(k+t)\big)$ is a point in the graph, then by symmetry about the line $x=k$ we have that $\big(k-t,p(k+t)\big)$ also lies in the graph of $p$. Since the points in the graph are of the form $\big(x,p(x)\big)$, this means $p(k-t)=p(k+t)$.

Comment: $t$ is the only variable in the relation. You may call it $x$ if you prefer to. $a,b,c,d$ and $k$ are given (constants).

Comment: I got after solving that relation the following eqn $2(t^3)+3(k)^2+(2bk+c)t$$=0$

Comment: How to proceed after this

Comment: That's... not what I got.

Comment: Could you share your answer, I'll recheck mine.

Comment: I've edited the question. I had made a mistake writing the equation, please check if you're using the new equation

Comment: See the edit. Try and check your calculations. I didn't do them by hand, I used Maple, so I'm pretty confident in the result.

Comment: Thank you. This particular problem had been bothering me for quite some time. Greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: I have added a little extra in the end. Glad to help nonetheless!